# Como converter resultado de pesquisa no mysql em colunas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Boa noite galera, não sei se alguém passou por isso, mas estou precisando converter o resultado de uma pesquisa em mysql em colunas, não é trocar as linhas pelas colunas, mas sim, fazer com que alguns resultados se tornem os títulos da coluna.

Sendo:

```
NOME        DATA
fulano      2016-01-10
fulano      2016-02-15
fulano      2016-03-10
beltrano    2016-01-10
ciclano     2016-02-15
ciclano     2016-03-10
beltrano    2016-04-10
```

Deveria ficar assim:

```
NOME        2016-01-10         2016-02-15         2016-03-10       2016-04-10
fulano           X                  X                  X
beltrano         X                                                      X
ciclano                             X                  X
```

Sendo que essas datas são dinâmicas, armazenadas em outra tabela no banco de dados.

Não sei se é possível fazer esse tipo de query, mas desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: o que seria o valor x?

Comment: Isso seria uma tabela de presença?

Comment: Exatamente, é uma tabela de presença. O valor X seria substituído por F ou P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer o que você quer com uma query, mas temos algumas limitações.

Por exemplo, você **teria que construir a query já sabendo quantas colunas** você teria de resultado, que **seriam os dias** da sua tabela.

Um exemplo:

```
SELECT resultado.nome,
       COALESCE(MAX(resultado.dia_20160110), '') AS '2016-01-10',
       COALESCE(MAX(resultado.dia_20160215), '') AS '2016-02-15',
       COALESCE(MAX(resultado.dia_20160310), '') AS '2016-03-10',
       COALESCE(MAX(resultado.dia_20160410), '') AS '2016-04-10'
  FROM (  SELECT t.nome,
                 CASE WHEN t.dataaula =  '2016-01-10' THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS dia_20160110,
                 CASE WHEN t.dataaula =  '2016-02-15' THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS dia_20160215,
                 CASE WHEN t.dataaula =  '2016-03-10' THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS dia_20160310,
                 CASE WHEN t.dataaula =  '2016-04-10' THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS dia_20160410
            FROM teste t  ) AS resultado
 GROUP BY resultado.nome
```

Veja só, **eu indiquei na query quais seriam as datas transformadas em colunas**. A cada nova data, uma nova coluna seria necessária, ou seja, uma alteração na query.

Você até poderia escrever um programa/script que gerenciasse isso pra você e resultasse na query que seria executada em determinado momento.

Para testar e fazer modificações você pode acessar aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f55b41/10

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou sim, vou estudar essa estrutura e ver como posso dinamizar essas colunas.

Comment: Que bom amigo. Se a solução resolveu seu problema não esqueça de sinalizar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Essa solução funciona, porém, ainda não é o que preciso, vou continuar tentando, mesmo assim agradeço a ajuda.